# Generating a sum of up / down ratings up to 100%

Tags: php

I wrote a grading system (up / down). Users save the votes in the database:

```
articles (
   id int not null auto_increment,
   article_title varchar (100) not null,
   ...
   vote_up int not null default '0',
   vote_down int not null default '0',
   vote_sum int not null default '0'
   ..
)
```

And I would like to display a bar showing the status of up / down ratings as here: [image: http://imgadd.net/im/1b7bc480c9.png]

How can I percent up / down grades? Do you have any idea?

Comment: Do you have any try?

Comment: I'm guessing doing a simple `vote_up / vote_sum` is not the issue here. What then? Try to be _specific_.

Comment: Do you want like this : https://3v4l.org/8jagK

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by creating 2-spans (or divs) & change their percentage width accordingly.

for ex. if vote_up = 20 & vote_down = 30 then

```
    total_votes = vote_up + vote_down;

    vote_up_pctg = vote_up/total_votes *100;
    vote_down_pctg = vote_down/total_votes *100;
```

so first span or div width will be 40% & for second will be 60%.

You have to do it all of the above in CSS & PHP (or any server side language). You can do this also in js but it will take some time after loading.